# APT repository for old debian squeeze ARM

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, apt

I have ARM based board with debian squeeze with kernel 3.3.3. I have been using it with

```
deb http://www.emdebian.org/grip squeeze main dev
```

It stopped working couple months ago, so I switched to

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian squeeze main
```

Today I noticed it's not working anymore. Where can I find repository for squeeze armel? For example I need `perl-base_5.10.1-17squeeze6_armel.deb` and many many others.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this problem too. I got it to work using the old releases archive:

deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main